# How to disable google updater, running in background as googleupdate.exe?

Tags: windows, process, services, google-updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop the Google Update background tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/114815/how-to-stop-the-google-update-background-tool)

Hello,

How to disable google updater, running in background as googleupdate.exe ?

I tried Googling but none worked me well !

Since I am using a limited broadband connection, auto update really breaks my head

Please help me to solve this

OS: Windows XP SP2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't mention which Windows operating system you're using, but the differences in these instructions for Windows XP or Windows 7 will be minor.

To disbale the GoogleUpdater service:

1. Click the Start menu
2. Click Run
3. Type in `services.msc' and the Services MMC will open
4. Now you will need to locate the GoogleUpdater service in the list, then double-click on it to open the "Properties" window
5. To stop the GoogleUpdater from running when you boot your computer, change the Startup Type to "Disabled"
6. To stop the GoogleUpdater service right now, click the "Stop" button.

Now, you also want to delete the Scheduled Task that runs the GoogleUpdater:

(For Windows XP)

1. Navigate to the Control Panel
2. Go into Scheduled Tasks
3. If a task called "GoogleUpdateTaskUser" exists, delete it.

(For Windows Vista / 7)

1. Navigate to the Control Panel
2. Go into Administrative Tools
3. Go into Task Scheduler
4. If a task called "GoogleUpdateTaskUser" exists, delete it.

Comment: On the scheduled task, it may be hidden.  On XP, there is an option on the Advanced menu, View Hidden Tasks.

Comment: I like to stop them from starting through msconfig but I'm not sure which one is more correct.

Comment: @wag2639 - in msconfig, do you mean you stop GoogleUpdater in the "Startup" tab? This will only stop it from being executed at system start up; if the Scheduled Task happens to run then GoogleUpdater will be executed on your system. To stop it entirely, you would also need to disable the service (and delete the Scheduled Task if you didn't do that already).

Comment: I was merely suggesting it as an alternative to `services.msc` but I'm not sure which way is better. I agree with your task scheduler details.

Comment: Doesn't `msconfig` pop up every startup?

Comment: @Hello71 No, if you check "Don't come up next restart, or I will kill you", it won't.

Answer (score 1):

I used Soluto to disable launch on boot
http://soluto.com